# WCF XML serialization message format

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization, format, message

I would like to receive an input message following this format:

```
<abc:message xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com" specver="0730">
    <abc:myrequest msgid="0123">
        <abc:AttID>3</abc:AttID>
        <abc:AuthNb>100</abc:AuthNb>
```

I wrote the following code to do so:

**Interface**:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract(Name = "message")]
        string RequestData(MyMessageRequest message);
```

**Data Contracts**:

```
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
    public class MyMessageRequest
    {

        [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.example.com", AttributeName = "specver")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "myrequest")]
        public MyRequest MyRequest { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
    public class MyRequest
    {
        
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "msgid")]
        public string MsgId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AttID")]
        public string AttributionID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AuthNb")]
        public int AuthenticationNumber { get; set; }
```

When I import my WSDL into SoapUI, I get the following pre-defined request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eft="http://www.eftpos2000.ch" xmlns:exam="http://www.example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <eft:message>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <eft:message specver="?">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <exam:myrequest msgnum="?">
               <!--Optional:-->
               <exam:AcqID>?</exam:AcqID>
               <exam:AmtAuth>?</exam:AmtAuth>
```

As you will notice, I have two times an element named "message".

Any ideas how to remove the XML root element "message"?

BR
Nicolas

Comment: The following gets the one level : [XmlElement(ElementName = "myrequest")]  To get the two levels replace with : [XmlArray("myrequest")]  and [XmlArrayItem("myrequest")]

Comment: I do not need any array. I want to get rid of one "myrequest" element.

Comment: Is you SOAPUI going to change which has two elements?  The XML serialization for arrays (public MyRequest[] MyRequest { get; set; }) Have two options 1) Have one xml element and use XmlElement 2) Have two xml elements and use XmlArray and XmlArrayItem.  Right now your SOAP has two xml elements, but you say you want to have only one.  You can't support both options.

Comment: Yes, exactly: only one element within the message. So I guess no need to declare an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable name in your method is ***myrequest***, and the first ***myrequest*** is the variable name of the method:

[image]

I modified it to ***message***,the following picture is the request format required in SoapUI:

[image]

This is the ***MyMessageRequest*** class:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
public class MyMessageRequest
{

    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.example.com",AttributeName = "specver")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "myrequest")]
    public MyRequest MyRequest { get; set; }

}
```

***UPDATE***

[image]

[image]

The first ***message*** is a node encapsulated by the operationcontract. You can delete it, but it will generate a node with the default method name, you cannot delete this.

Comment: Thanks ! I validated your approach, however I am also looking to delete the first root element "message". I am editing my initial post.